# How to select proper java data structure to model a 1-n relational mapping?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, oop, concurrency

**Scenario**

I'm going to be as succinct as possible. Basically with reference to this [classdiag](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37403003@N08/3548515830/), I have a facade which manages a list of **SocketManager** ( which manages one Socket connection). Each **SocketManager** logs in to a remote server using a unique *SocketUserId*. Furthermore, each **SocketManager** will accept messages from clients destined for a specific list of **Receipients**. For discussion sake, consider these **Receipients** as simply as remote data buckets identified by a name.

Clients will send data like this:

```
SocketFacade facade = ...;

byte[] data = ...

facade.sendData( receipient, data );
```

When *SocketFacade* starts, it will query a mysql table which returns the 1-m relationship between *SocketUserId* and *Receipients*. I will use a [MultiValuedMap](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) to represent this 1-m relationship. Multiple **SocketManager** will be then be started by iterating through the map.

```
(1) Map< SocketUserId, List<Receipient> >
```

e.g. Suppose we have 2 **SocketManager**s with *SocketUserId*s "alice" & "tom" respectively

```
            +----SocketManager1 ( "alice" ) for Receipients { "B", "C" }
            |
 SocketFacade 
            |
            +----SocketManager2 ( "tom" ) for Receipients { "A", "D" }
```

**Question**

I am in a bind as to how to implement the *sendData* method. Basically I need a way to map from a Receipient (e.g. "B") to its responsible **SocketManager** (e.g. *SocketManager1*).

Let's suppose I do this

```
(2) Map< SocketUserId, SocketManager >
(3) Map< Receipient, SocketUserId >
```

- Would I need a SoftReference for the value in (2) ?
- Should I just map from **Receipient** directly to **SocketManager** ?
- **SocketFacade** also supports methods that will mutate the relationship represented by (1). If I write to the database, the in-memory data structures in (1), (2), & (3) will need to change in sync. **SocketFacade** must be thread safe as well. Initial idea is to have some sort of a publish subscribe system whereby an add/remove to the DB will cause the changes to propagate via callbacks.

  ```
  interface Callback
  {
      void receipientAdded( Receipient r );
      void receipientDeleted( Receipient r );
  }
  ```

Comment: It is "recipient", not "receipient".  Spelling errors in code are an annoying source of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the `SocketManager` in each `Receipient`. That way, you can avoid the map (which needs more RAM, is slower and doesn't add any value).

In the `SocketManager`, keep a list of `Receipient`'s. As you add and remove the `Receipient`'s, update the pointer to the `SocketManager`.

In the `SocketFacade`, you need a map which takes the `SocketUserId` and returns a `SocketManager`. That map is filled by querying for the IDs in the map. After all managers exist, add the recipients to each. That takes two SQL queries.

This is very easy to map with any ORM tool.

Comment: In my opinion it isn't very nice to put the SocketManager into the recipient. The Recipient would then expose the SocketManager to the SocketFacade's client/caller. The question behind this is "Does the Recipient need to know which SocketManager is responsible for him.". As how I understand this scenario, this isn't desired and should be hidden behind the facade. It's just a matter of the facade's setup. Am I getting this right so far?

Comment: Fundamentally I want to dispatch the message supplied to SocketFacade#sendData(..) to the right SocketManager. That is all. The Recipient is identified by an String identifier. Another design criteria is to be able to add & remove Receipients that are handled by a particular SocketManager (this involves an in-memory change plus a database update). To answer your question, the Recipient ideally should not need to know about what SocketManager it is related to.

Comment: @rudolfson: Ah, then I misunderstood. I thought this is like "send a message to all recipients of a SocketManager". Hm. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a 1-1 relationship between SocketUserId and SocketManager, can't you just add a reference to the SocketUserId in the SocketMananger, and a reference to the SocketManager in the Recipient ?

Then you would have in your facade one Map containing the recipient, and the List of SocketManager. In the `sendData` function you would get the recipient From the map, and obtain from this recipient the reference to its SocketManager.

regards

Guillaume

Comment: I was apprehensive about sticking the SocketManager into a map at first because underneath it runs 2 threads and a Socket channel. I'm planning to hold a List<SocketManager> so that is is convenient for me to iterate and call shutdown. What do you think ? Yes SocketManager will have a ref to a SocketUserId( 1-1 ). Since one Recipient is related to only one SocketManager, why would I need a List of SocketManager ? From your idea, I'll just have Map< ReceipientKey, Recipient>. Do I understand you correctly ?

Comment: @ashitaka: Huh? From your example, SocketManager to Recipient is 1:N!

Comment: @AaronDigulla I made a mistake. I meant to say that "Since one SocketUserId is related to only one SocketManager ...". SocketManager to Recipient is 1:N

Comment: Yes. From my point of view, the List of SocketManager is not strictly necessary, but as you said, you may want to manage the socketManager (start, stop, get the current state, get some information on traffic...)

Answer (score 1):

At an abstract level, you have: 1 `Thing` that relates to n `OtherThing`s.  You could model this by creating a special relationship object that refers back to `Thing` and contains a `java.util.List<OtherThing>` of references to the n `OtherThing`s.  This leaves your domain objects (Things) uncluttered with relationship information.  But if it seems right, its simpler to add the `java.util.List` directly to class `Thing` (or a subclass).  The List variable can be left null and populated with a `java.util.ArrayList<OtherThing>` only when you need to establish the relationship.